systemd-networkd DHCP server Failed to configure address pool for DHCPv4 server instance: Numerical result out of range
I am using systemd networkd version 253.1. I have 2 ethernet ports on my Linux 5.15 box and I want to setup a DHCP server on the second port. I had successfully done that with the following configuration for eth1.
Working DHCP Server configuration:
[Match]
Name=eth1
Type=ether

[DHCPV4]
DUIDType=link-layer
ClientIdentifier=mac

[Network]
Address=172.1.17.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
#IPMasquerade=ipv4

[DHCPServer]
PoolOffset=1
PoolSize=8

Now, I want the change the range to the following:
[Match]
Name=eth1
Type=ether

[DHCPV4]
DUIDType=link-layer
ClientIdentifier=mac

[Network]
#
# 10.1.193.24/29
#
#  Network Address: 10.1.193.24
#  Usable IP Range: 10.1.193.25 - 10.1.193.30
#  Broadcast Address: 10.1.193.31
#
Address= 10.1.193.24/29
DHCPServer=yes
#IPMasquerade=ipv4

[DHCPServer]
PoolOffset=2
PoolSize=5

However, I get the error shown below:
[root@machine ~]$  networkctl status eth1 -l
* 3: eth1
                     Link File: n/a
                  Network File: /etc/systemd/network/eth1.network
                         State: routable (failed)
                  Online state: online
                          Type: ether
                          Path: platform-30bf0000.ethernet
              Hardware Address: 00:01:c0:37:6d:56 (Company, Ltd.)
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 46, max: 9000)
                         QDisc: mq
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
      Number of Queues (Tx/Rx): 8/8
              Auto negotiation: yes
                         Speed: 1Gbps
                        Duplex: full
                          Port: tp
                       Address: 10.1.193.24
                                fe80::201:c0ff:fe37:6d56
             Activation Policy: up
           Required For Online: yes
             DHCP6 Client DUID: DUID-EN/Vendor:0000ab1180dd9f24e9435b570000
           Offered DHCP leases: none

Aug 12 14:33:07 machine systemd-networkd[654]: eth1: Received new foreign route (configured): dst: 10.1.193.24/29, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 10.1.193.24, scope: link, table: main(254), proto: kernel, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0, flags: n/a
Aug 12 14:33:07 machine systemd-networkd[654]: eth1: Addresses set
Aug 12 14:33:07 machine systemd-networkd[654]: eth1: link_check_ready(): dynamic addresses or routes are not configured.
Aug 12 14:33:07 machine systemd-networkd[654]: eth1: Configuring DHCP Server.
Aug 12 14:33:07 machine systemd-networkd[654]: eth1: Failed to configure address pool for DHCPv4 server instance: Numerical result out of range
Aug 12 14:33:07 machine systemd-networkd[654]: eth1: Failed to configure DHCP server: Numerical result out of range
Aug 12 14:33:07 machine systemd-networkd[654]: eth1: Failed
Aug 12 14:33:07 machine systemd-networkd[654]: eth1: State changed: configuring -> failed
Aug 12 14:33:07 machine systemd-networkd[654]: eth1: LLDP Rx: Stopping LLDP client
Aug 12 14:33:07 machine systemd-networkd[654]: eth1: NDISC: Stopping IPv6 Router Solicitation client

I've checked various CIDR calculators and I believe my configuration file parameters are valid.

Why does networkd not accept my config file?


I think the problem here is that 10.1.193.24 is the .0 address for this CIDR range; that would be like assigning the address 192.168.1.0 to a host on the 192.168.1.0/24 network. Many systems consider this a broadcast address. It looks like systemd-networkd will not allow you to assign this address to an interface.
The following configuration works fine for me:
[Match]
Name=eth1
Type=ether

[DHCPV4]
DUIDType=link-layer
ClientIdentifier=mac

[Network]
Address=10.1.193.25/29
DHCPServer=yes

[DHCPServer]
PoolOffset=2
PoolSize=4

Note the reduced pool size, since with the server address at 10.1.193.25 and an offset of 2, we have the following addresses available:
10.1.193.27
10.1.193.28
10.1.193.29
10.1.193.30

10.1.193.31 is the broadcast address.
Bringing this up, I see in the logs:
Aug 12 21:35:26 localhost systemd-networkd[699]: eth1: Link UP
Aug 12 21:35:26 localhost systemd-networkd[699]: eth1: Gained carrier
Aug 12 21:35:26 localhost systemd-networkd[699]: eth1: found matching network '/etc/systemd/network/internal.network', based on potentially unpredictable interface name.
Aug 12 21:35:27 localhost systemd-networkd[699]: eth1: Gained IPv6LL

And the interface looks like:
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:a6:d6:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0
    inet 10.1.193.25/29 brd 10.1.193.31 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fea6:d6f9/64 scope link proto kernel_ll
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

As expected, if I bring up five machines on this network, four of them are able to successfully acquire a DHCP lease:
# tcpdump -i eth1 -nn port bootps or port bootpc
21:51:12.762858 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 52:54:00:66:78:aa, length 282
21:51:12.762990 IP 10.1.193.25.67 > 10.1.193.27.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 279
21:51:12.879438 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 52:54:00:9e:d6:aa, length 282
21:51:12.879518 IP 10.1.193.25.67 > 10.1.193.26.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 279
21:51:13.334272 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 52:54:00:09:97:9b, length 276
21:51:14.014954 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 52:54:00:44:0f:e6, length 282
21:51:14.015032 IP 10.1.193.25.67 > 10.1.193.29.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 279
21:51:14.065205 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 52:54:00:c1:4f:c8, length 282
21:51:14.065322 IP 10.1.193.25.67 > 10.1.193.28.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 279
21:51:15.568213 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 52:54:00:09:97:9b, length 276
21:51:19.808546 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 52:54:00:09:97:9b, length 276
21:51:28.489925 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 52:54:00:09:97:9b, length 276

In the above output, you can see for Reply messages. The host at address 52:54:00:09:97:9b was unable to get a lease because all the available addresses had already been assigned to other hosts.

Thank you - I can now bring the interface up successfully.
